# Selecting value for the latest two distinct columns

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to do an SQL which will return the latest data value of the two distinct columns of my table.

Currently, I select distinct the values of the column and afterwards, I iterate through the columns to get the distinct values selected before then order and limit to 1. These tags can be any number and may not always be posted together (one time only tag 1 can be posted; whereas other times 1, 2, 3 can).

Although it gives the expected outcome, this seems to be inefficient in a lot of ways, and because I don't have enough SQL experience, this was so far the only way I found of performing the task...

```
--------------------------------------------------
|  name   |   tag   |   timestamp  |    data     |
--------------------------------------------------
|   aa    |    1    |      566     |    4659     |
--------------------------------------------------
|   ab    |    2    |      567     |    4879     |
--------------------------------------------------
|   ac    |    3    |      568     |    1346     |
--------------------------------------------------
|   ad    |    1    |      789     |    3164     |
--------------------------------------------------
|   ae    |    2    |      789     |    1024     |
--------------------------------------------------
|   af    |    3    |      790     |    3346     |
--------------------------------------------------
```

Therefore the expected outcome is {3164, 1024, 3346}

Currently what I'm doing is:

```
"select distinct tag from table"
```

Then I store all the distinct tag values programmatically and iterate programmatically through these values using

```
"select data from table where '"+ tags[i] +"' in (tag) order by timestamp desc limit 1"
```

Thanks,

Comment: I've removed all irrelevant tags, because this a pure SQL question. You simply need to come up with a single query for your table, that's all.

Answer (score 0):

This comes close, but beware if you have two rows with the same tag share a maximum timestamp you will get duplicates in the result set

```
select data from table 
join (select tag, max(timestamp) maxtimestamp from table t1 group by tag) as latesttags 
on table.tag = latesttags.tag and table.timestamp = latesttags.maxtimestamp
```